# SumIF, while ignoring hidden rows and using extra criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

My original formula is

```
=SUMIF($D$5:$D$250;"A";G$5:G$250)
```

which sums up all cells from G5:G250 that have a value of "A" in D5:D250.
Now I am going to hide a few rows and I want them to be excluded from the summation. According to my research, my formula should be changed into someting like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX($G$5:$G$250,1,1),ROW($G$5:$G$250)-ROW(INDEX($G$5:$G$250,1,1)),0))=1),--($D$5:$B$250="A"),$G$5:$G$250)
```

However, the formula does not work and I can not find the reason why.

Hope it makes sense. Furthermore, I am new to Excel and could be making some obvious mistakes. My apologies in advance.

Comment: There is an obvious mistake where the B should be a D, but the formula still gives an error after correcting it.

Comment: You use the word "hidden", not "filtered out", in which case the initial parameter in SUBTOTAL should be 103, not 3.

Comment: You are right. I changed it into 103, but the same problem still occurs. Excel is not very specific and just says that there is a problem with my formula.

Comment: What precise error message do you get?

Comment: "We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert Function on the Formulas tab to fix it, or click Help for more info on common formula problems."

Comment: Does your system use the comma as argument-separator in formulas, or the semi-colon?

Comment: That was it! I exchanged all the commas for the semi-colons and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your system uses the semicolon as argument-separator in formulas, not the comma?

Regards